# how to encode the tags in an article?

Tags: php, html, mysql, encode

i have a simple WYSIWYG editor in a php form. For example the form returns  :

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <h2>adipiscing elit</h2>. Nunc consectetur metus libero. eleifend ultricies. Pellentesque et <img src="qddffdv/zsdsfdf.png /> vestibulum quam. Nullam efficitur tellus <b>venenatis porttitor</b> suscipit. In in euismod ligula, in egestas nulla. Nunc quis condimentum elit. .`

Before, i saved this in a MYSQL database.
Now, i want to do a short resume of this article, but he returns me :

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <h2>adipiscing elit</h2>. Nunc consectetur metus libero. eleifend ultricies. Pellentesque et <img src="qddffdv/fdf`

So, how can i encode html tags for save an article in a database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before cut whole article to digest you can remove html tags: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

`strip-tags` won't do what you want since it will remove the HTML markup.

Instead what you should use is the `htmlentities` function, which will return a string with the tags converted to the applicable HTML entities which are safe for storing in a database.

Simply put your article content through this function and then save the result to the database.

There's more information on this function [here](http://php.net/htmlentities).

Comment: Topic starter don't need simple store result to database. He needs to correctly convert the original article in a short digest, without breaking with the html tags.